# High Level Graphics

Tags: opengl, java-3d, vrml

I did a lot of VRML+Java work in college and loved it, but I feel like it's not really a marketable skill.  Has anyone worked with a high level graphics API like open inventor, coin..etc that is actually in use to a degree that makes investing a lot of time in the API worthwhile for something more than a hobby?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some industries that need such graphics programming skills:

- Entertainment - Dreamworks, Pixar
- Engineering - companies into Computation Fluid mechanics/ Dynamics (CFM, CDM)
- Gaming - EA Games and so on

Also check with companies into "photo realistic rendering".

So yes those skills will surely get you a nice job. If you take a look at the 'careers' or 'jobs' section of these companies you should get a pretty good idea of which particular api to develop on.

Answer (score 0):

I come from an scientific visualisation background and have used Open Inventor for years.  I started my own business last year and my first consulting job was to a large mining company to build a 3D visualisation system based on Open Inventor (using the .Net bindings from Mercury).

While 3D visualisation might be somewhat specialised, there is a growing need for these skills - many industries are "going 3D".  With this comes opportunities, so you can definitely make a living off 3D visualisation.  I would encourage you to follow your heart a little here; if you love 3D graphics, then skill up and make it part of your career.

In my opinion you should focus on the required mathematics, building a depth of knowledge in this area, and have some experience with a selection of technologies like OpenGL, DirectX, Open Inventor, Java 3D or some other scenegraph.  You could also write your own scenegraph to build your skills.

A good understanding of current hardware capabilities and hardware trends is essential.